# Android popup with checkboxes

Tags: android, checkbox, popupwindow

In my app I would like to have something quite similar to Android's built in popup menu (see link below), but it also needs to include checkboxes and images and I should be able to choose several checkboxes before closing (with the same button that opened it). Is it possible to do that with [android popup menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu)? Is there a better way? Any chance there is a way to do it on android 2.1 (this the version on my demonstration device)?

Thanks for your time,
Lior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the overflow menu in Android 3+. But there is a way to use it in lower APIs by just using [ActionBar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). See the demo App of the ABS. There is also a demonstation of it. 
It should look something like [this](https://a248.e.akamai.net/camo.github.com/e1d9b5eeab84fc2b15a6e101afba2a0f3f317301/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f79733651452e706e67.).

Comment: This is not exactly the solution I was hoping for, but I might try that later on. Thanks